# FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to run a simple FB graph request for a user's cover photo, but am getting an error that I can't find too much about.

```
(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) ? NSLog(@"is open") : NSLog(@"is closed");

//cover photo
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/fields=cover"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              // Sucess! Include your code to handle the results here
                              NSLog(@"user events: %@", result);
                          } else {
                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors   
                          }
                      }];
```

Error:

```
FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint 'me/fields=cover': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.
```

I thought it could be a FBSession issue, but It prints out "is open" so it seems there is a valid active session.

Any ideas to what the problem is?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use graph path like this:

```
@"me?fields=cover"
```

And first, you should try every path on [Facebook's Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)